# How to get value for second dynamic drop down list?

Tags: javascript, html, web, drop-down-menu, lookup-tables

My program is ment to update the second drop down menu according to the selection made in the first drop down menu, and then update a third drop down menu according to the selection made in the second. it seems like ive gotten everything down so far.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scratch.js" defer></script>
</head>

<select id="pipe_mat_HTML" onchange="secondSelection()">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
    <option value="PVC_Water">PVC For Water Mains</option>
    <option value="PVC_Gravity">PVC For Gravity Sewer </option>
    <option value="PVC_IPS">PVC Pressure Rated PIP (IPS)</option>
    <option value="Iron">Ductile Iron Pipe</option>
    <option value="HDPE_IPS">HDPE Pipe (IPS)</option>
    <option value="HDPE_DIPS">HDPE Pipe (DIPS)</option>
    <option value="Steel">Steel (NPS)</option>
</select>

 <!-- Second drop-down menu -->
<select id="pipe_size_HTML" onchange="thirdSelection()">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
</select>

<select id="pipe_WT_HTML">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var lookupTable = {
  "PVC_Water": {
    "4\"": [
      "DR-14",
      "DR-18",
      "DR-21",
      "DR-25"
    ],
    "6\"": [
      "DR-14",
      "DR-18",
      "DR-21",
      "DR-25"
    ]
  }
};

function secondSelection() {
    // Get the selected value from the first drop-down menu
    var pipe_mat_value = document.getElementById("pipe_mat_HTML").value;

    // Get a reference to the second drop-down menu
    var pipe_size = document.getElementById("pipe_size_HTML");

    // Remove all existing options from the second drop-down menu
    pipe_size.innerHTML = "";

    for (const key in lookupTable[pipe_mat_value]) {
        pipe_size.add(new Option(key, "pipe_size_value"));
    }
}

function thirdSelection() {
    // Get the selected value from the first drop-down menu
    var pipe_mat_value = document.getElementById("pipe_mat_HTML").value;

    // Get a reference to the second drop-down menu
    var pipe_size_value = document.getElementById("pipe_size_HTML").value;

    var pipe_WT = document.getElementById("pipe_WT_HTML");

    console.log(pipe_WT);

    console.log(pipe_size_value);

    // Remove all existing options from the second drop-down menu
    pipe_WT.innerHTML = "";

    var WT_array = lookupTable[pipe_mat_value][pipe_size_value];

    WT_array.forEach(function(element) {
        pipe_WT.add(new Option(element, "pipe_WT_value"));
    });

    console.log(WT_array);

}
```

For some reason my `var pipe_size_value = document.getElementById("pipe_size_HTML").value;` seems to be returning `pipe_size_value` instead of returning the actual value associated with that variable. How can I make it so that variable returns the selection that is made? All values are pulled from a look up table

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact issue with your code, but I have the following suggestion. Main points:

- You just need one event listener for the entire form.
- Don't use IDs for fields. Use the name attribute instead. Then it is easy to refer to a field when you have en form context.
- Both the option value and the displayed text should have the same value (maybe this is actually your issue).
- When removing options you can use [HTMLSelectElement.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove) with an index and then keep the option with index 0.

```js
var lookupTable = {
  "PVC_Water": {
    "4\"": [
      "DR-14",
      "DR-18",
      "DR-21",
      "DR-25"
    ],
    "6\"": [
      "DR-14",
      "DR-18",
      "DR-21",
      "DR-25"
    ]
  }
};

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let pipe_mat_value = form.pipe_mat.value;
  var pipe_size_value = form.pipe_size.value;
  switch(e.target.name){
    case 'pipe_mat':
      while(form.pipe_size.item(1)){
        form.pipe_size.remove(1);
      }
      Object.keys(lookupTable[pipe_mat_value]).forEach(item => {
        form.pipe_size.add(new Option(item, item));
      });
      break;
    case 'pipe_size':
      while(form.pipe_WT.item(1)){
        form.pipe_WT.remove(1);
      }
      lookupTable[pipe_mat_value][pipe_size_value].forEach(item => {
        form.pipe_WT.add(new Option(item, item));
      });
      break;
    case 'pipe_WT':
      console.log("You selected", pipe_mat_value, pipe_size_value, e.target.value);
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <select name="pipe_mat">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
    <option value="PVC_Water">PVC For Water Mains</option>
    <option value="PVC_Gravity">PVC For Gravity Sewer </option>
    <option value="PVC_IPS">PVC Pressure Rated PIP (IPS)</option>
    <option value="Iron">Ductile Iron Pipe</option>
    <option value="HDPE_IPS">HDPE Pipe (IPS)</option>
    <option value="HDPE_DIPS">HDPE Pipe (DIPS)</option>
    <option value="Steel">Steel (NPS)</option>
  </select>

  <select name="pipe_size">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
  </select>

  <select name="pipe_WT">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: *Both the option value and the displayed text should have the same value (maybe this is actually your issue)* - It is. The `Option` constructor used in the loop in OP's `secondSelection()` is using `pipe_size_value` as the second argument.